# How to Perform SQL insert or update command using SQL injection

Tags: sql-injection

I have a URL `http://localhost/usernfo.php?id=8` on which SQL injection can be performed.

How can I perform an Update, Insert or Delete command from this link after 
I have got the structure of the database?

Comment: It depends on how you succeeded to perform the injection. Tell us how you did that and we could help.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say the application uses the id parameter (which is in your example 8) to create the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=8 and active=1
```

If the parameter id is injectable, you could for example in the URL instead of 8 enter the following:

```
8; UPDATE table_name SET filed=123456 --
```

That would turn the first query into:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=8; UPDATE table_name SET filed=123456 -- and active=1
```

With ; you are closing the first query, and with -- you are commenting out if anything remained from the first query.

Comment: Sorry but it depends, if the underlying function is mysql_query (php) as example, it doesn't support stacked queries. (http://www.sqlinjection.net/stacked-queries/)

Comment: @r00t, if someone is going to inject an insert or update statement this is how it would be done though, correct?  I understand that it might not be possible, depending on the underlying code, but I don't know of another way to do it.

Comment: @AbeMiessler : Yes sure, but the answer should be clear on the fact that it's not always possible to UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT. The OP asked "how can i perform[...]" and the exact answer is : you may be able to do it like the pineappleman said or may not be able to do it at all. Also, the answer is assuming the underlying request is a SELECT but the GET var could also be used in an UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT or a stored procedure, etc.. so the answer is not covering all cases.

Comment: @r00t The OP specified that we should assume that "SQL injection can be performed".

Comment: @TTT : Yes, but it's not because "SQL injection can be performed" that you can execute INSERT, UPDATE AND DELETE statements...

Comment: @r00t: I was referring to your statement, "you may be able to do it like the pineappleman said or may not be able to do it at all". I simply meant to point out that OP specified that we should assume it can be done, which conflicts with your latter option.

Comment: @TTT : being able to do an SQL injection doesn't mean you can execute whatever statement you want... The question is about "Update, Insert or Delete" so it's a specific statement. I just pointed out that the answer is not complete and can also be false depending on the case.

Comment: @r00t I agree with you. It is good that you pointed it out because it is an important info.

Comment: @r00t - ah! I see what you mean now. I thought "it" meant "Sql Injection", instead of "INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE". Though after reading your clarification again, I'm not sure how I missed your point. It's extremely clear now though.